# Pygame will not import into python 2.7.1

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

This is the below error that comes up:

```
File "/Users/coltonmalich/Desktop/blankpygame.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame, sys
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

any help would be appreciated.
Colton

Comment: Can you share your blankpygame.py code?

Comment: Looks like the so file can't run on your system , maybe the so file is compile for x84 architecture, and you are using arm architecture. Do you mind to share me your system? looks like you are using mac?

Comment: Yes I am using a Mac. Here is the code: import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
All it is supposed t do so far is show me a blank window with "Hello World" as the title. What part did you want from my system? Sorry, I am a relative beginner in all of this!

Comment: After chopping the code up piece by piece, I see John was correct. It will not import at all. I downloaded and installed the correct file I thought. I thought my mac was a 32 bit but searching the apple forums, having an intel Core i5 which is stated that it is a 64 bit. Back to searching I go!

Comment: So you've got a 64-bit CPU. How did you install Pygame?

Comment: I installed it from the pygame website. I have 64 bit turned off and I downloaded the pygame version for python 2.7 which is what I have. I installed it and then created the python code and tried running it.

Comment: Alright. What do you mean by you turned off 64-bit?

Comment: On the mac you can switch between 32 and 64 bit.